# other option beside document.body.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

this is my code

```
  const printDiv = () => {
    const printContents = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML;
    const originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

    return false;
  };
```

i know when i using innerHTML gives me a string representation of the HTML within an element so i can't handle button or something like that.

actually, i can handle it with reload, but what is the best way? is there any option without reload which make me back to the same page?

Comment: why don't you open the printable content in a new tab?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi using window open? how to open new window with getElementByiD? because i already styling the pdf in that id

Comment: CSS? `@media print { /* hide all but #id */ }` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: @Andreas do you know, how to implement it in js?

Answer (score -1):

```
const printContents = document.getElementById('id')
const win = window.open();
win.document.title ="some title";
win.document.body.innerHTML = printContents.innerHTML;

/* if content contains images that needs loading*/
const images = win.document.getElementsByTagName('img');
/*wait for them to load*/

win.print();
```